# Jekyll blog site on git hub - Edits made to main.css won't apply to markdown files

Tags: html, css, github, jekyll, blogs

Everytime I edit the main.css file in the assets directory, the changes do not apply to my blog post, any idea why? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing a hard refresh in the web browser with `CTRL + F5` to reload all of the files and delete the cache?

Or if that isn't working, try going into developer tools in the web browser, select the `Network` tab and try to find the stylesheet file and check the content of it by right clicking and opening it in a new tab. This will help you find out if the file is being updated or not.

Comment: I am looking at the page source and it says that it is reading main.css except I see that the updates I made are not there. Any Idea why? I reset my browser and refreshed but nothing. None of the updates I made on the file on my computer are there on the browser.

Comment: Huh, that's odd. Is the github pages using a custom domain or just the default github one? Also would it be possible for you to post a link to the repo?

Comment: @tbot Servers also use cache. You can try to refresh server by clicking the css link in source and refresh, refresh... eventually it will read an existing file not a cached file with the same name. Do not recommend, but If you do bigger changes - it will change size of file, maybe the server will catch the change  :)